# Opengl java bouncing entities

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Hello this is actually my first question here.. I have been developing a opengl lwjgl game and I'm working on the entities class.I have accomplished to make an entity jump(ill use this for animals) but the "issue" (99.9% sure its my fault) is that each time the entity touches the terrain and jumps again the jump is higher as seen in the video I recorded this is the code for jump thz =D I just want the tree to move up always the same.

[Video](https://streamable.com/z62nd)

```
    double velocity = 0;
double initVelX;
double initVelZ;
double time = 0;
float x;
float y;
float z;

public void bounce() {

    double initialVelocity = 0.1;       
    double speed = 1/2500.0;

    if(time == 0) {
        velocity += initialVelocity;
    }
    time += speed;
    velocity = velocity - 9.8 * speed;
    if(y + velocity < 0.1){
        velocity *= -1;
    }
    y += velocity;
    setPosition(new Vector3f(getPosition().x,y,getPosition().z));
}
```

Comment: OK I probably explained my self wrong what I wanted it's just to maintain the jump always equally with same spe s velocity and y increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it just had to do a simple line of code and it even has the speed fluctuations correct:

```
double velocity = 0;
    double initVelX;
    double initVelZ;
    double time = 0;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    public void bounce() {

        double initialVelocity = 0.1;       
        double speed = 1/2500.0;

        if(time == 0) {
            velocity = initialVelocity;
        }

        time += speed;
        velocity = velocity - 9.8 * speed;
        if(y + velocity < 0.1){
            velocity *= -1;
            velocity = initialVelocity;
        }
        y += velocity;
        setPosition(new Vector3f(getPosition().x,y,getPosition().z));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be one of these increment statements:

```
velocity += initialVelocity;
time += speed;
velocity *= -1;
y += velocity;
```

Do you want all of these to keep rising continually? Because that's what will happen.
Which part of your code calculates the height of the jump?

Comment: velocity does not continually increase. The absolute value might, but it definitely changes the sign. Due to this, y is also not constantly rising. Also, this doesn't really read like an answer, more like a comment. If you want to give hints or ask for clarification, please do not post an answer.

Comment: You also missed the `velocity = velocity - 9.8 * speed` line which continually **decreases** velocity...

Comment: I explained my self wrong Sry for that what I really want is a normal bounce effect for example the entity to bounce always the same distance up on the link I attached the tree goes higher o , each jump which I don't want and I can't seem to solve the issue....

Comment: Nope the tree still goes higher on each jump

Comment: @Petereo: Then why did you accept the answer? Accepting an answer means you have what you wanted and no further answer are required.

Comment: that's good then, because don't have a certain amount of reputation can't help people with their problems because get flamed by the mods- brilliant. Can't answer can't get rep can't help :S